# .xsd to TypeScript using cxsd, cxsd not recognized

Tags: node.js, batch-file, typescript, xsd

I am trying to create typescript definitions from an xsd file using the npm library cxsd. I have installed windows-build-tools through npm to provide cxsd with the required tools. When I try to run

```
npm run cxsd http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd
```

as described on cxsd's GitHub(https://github.com/charto/cxsd) I get this error

```
'csxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I have included the script "cxsd":"csxd" in the package.json.

Comment: btw i have npm installed cxsd

Comment: Have you installed cxsd as a global package? `npm install cxsd -g`

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Yes I have as well as `npm install --save`

Comment: Have you added the global npm package dir to your path? `C:\npm\` for example. It should contain `cxsd.cmd` and `cxsd`

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks, you should make that an answer to get the credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the global npm package dir to your path `C:\npm` for example. It should contain cxsd.cmd` and cxsd -@AdrianLeonhard